# copy data from one table to another table(history) except one non-identity column

Tags: mysql

Consider an example `employee` table with `empid`, `empname`, `empsalary`, `empdepartment`, `empactivity`; 
and another `employee_history` table of the same columns with one extra identity column as `emphistory_id`.

Whenever I perform any `update`,`delete` or `insert` operations on `employee` table, `employee_history` table should also be updated but activity column should hold value whether it's inserted, deleted or updated.

Above mentioned, these are just example tables. In my requirement I have around 200 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added 
 AFTER INSERT ON total_loaner
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO Logtable (Field )
VALUES (new.Field);
```

Please  Refer this Link it will Help you...

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php

Comment: I have around 155 columns so do i dont think mentioning all fields will going to help me out. Do you have any other approach?