# MySQL: For every user, add a row to another table with that user's ID

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I have a bunch of users in a project in the `users` table. I have a second table I use for `notifications`. When a user gets a notification for him, its added to the notifications table with his `user_id` and a `read` (true/false) flag.

Now, if I want to add a notification for every user (such as site going offline, etc), how would I add a row for every user in the users table? The new rows would be exactly identical with the exception of the auto_incremented row id but each new row would have to specify the user id.

Of course I could write a script in php to generate a ton of sql queries to do this and send them all at once using a multi-query insertion, but that seems computationally expensive if I have thousands of users.

Conceptual query:
FOR users.id as user_id

`INSERT INTO notifications VALUES (,user_id=user_id,msg='We will be going offline at 5:00!',read='0')`

Is that do able?

Thanks!

Comment: You can refer [this question also][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054911/i-want-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-tablehistory-except-one-column-v/27054943#27054943

Comment: Insert into n(x, y, z) select (a, 'b', c) from m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have thousands of users, it doesn't matter to generate thousands of SQL querys, and send it to your MySQL server.

But things will change if you have millions of users.

One affordable choice is, write a notification to a table, for example, `system_notifications`. Display not only `notifications` but also `system_notifications` on your webpage.

And then save the ids for the users who have already read these notifications.

e.g.

```
system_notifications table
| id | message |

system_notifications_read_users table
| id | user_id |
```

Then, you can only operate your database when the user read the notifications.

And when your system notification expired, such as you have finished your downtime, you can remove it from both of tables said before.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was considering the system notifications option and had a feeling that may be my only option. I think Ill go with that for v1 of my product but would really like to look into triggers more. I have gone over the mysql documentation that was linked but it seemed overly confusing. Does anyone have a few simple examples they can use that would fit this situation or one like it?